# How to make sure web image is built after mysql container is up and running in docker-compose?

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Under the current build order

1. build localhost image
2. build web image
3. run localhost container
4. run web container

This will fail in step 2, since the java at src will not compile because it cannot to localhost, as localhost image is not running. The solution will be change the current build order to:

Under the current build order

1. build localhost image
2. run localhost container
3. build web image
4. run web container

How do I achieve that in dockerfile and/or docker-compose.yml?

Dockerfile

```
#Build
FROM maven:latest AS BUILD
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
RUN cd /usr/src/app &&\
    mvn install

#ENVIRONMENT
FROM openjdk:16
COPY --from=BUILD /usr/src/app/target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  localhost:
    image: mysql:5.7.34
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=virtual_election
      - MYSQL_USER=myapp-user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    network_mode: host
  web:
    image: web
    restart: on-failure
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - localhost
    network_mode: host
```

Comment: You have already achieved that with depends-on

Comment: Do you need to connect to the database to produce a `.jar` file?  What would happen if you ran the application against a different database?